# xml parser that allows both escaped and non-escaped characters

Tags: html, xml, lxml

I need an xml parser that will return me the exact text inside the node as provided. So for the node:

`<title>This is title of <i>special</i> book</title>`

if

`i = element.text`

then

`i` should be `"This is title of <i>special</i> book"`

but if

`<title>This is title of &lt;i&ht;special&lt;/i&gt; book</title>`

then

`i` should be `"This is title of &lt;i&ht;special&lt;/i&gt; book"`

The reason for this is that later I render these variables in the HTML templates and I need to render them as provided - either with the formatting or escaped tags.

I haven't found a way to do that with lxml - in fact, if provided with unescaped HTML tag it does not read the text correctly (in the above example it would be `i = "This is title of "`), and if provided with escaped HTML tag it unescapes it.

What is the correct alternative that I should use? Or maybe there is a way to do that with lxml?

Answer (score 0):

I would use custom function to determine whether node text is escaped or unescaped and optionally unescape it:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

def get_text(node):
  tag = node.tag
  text = node.text
  if len(f'<{tag}>{node.text}</{tag}>') == len(ET.tostring(root).decode()):
    return text
  else:
    return ET.tostring(node).decode().replace(f'<{tag}>', '').replace(f'</{tag}>', '')
```